# Displaying floating points in C

Tags: c, file, loops, structure, scanf

Right, i have a 2 files (Distance and time) that have different values on their rows, in the program that divides both values on line into their speed and displays on screen.

This works perfectly, however, the function gives the calculated value to the nearest whole number:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{

FILE *fTotDc;
FILE *fTotTc;

int CalScD;  //Values for total cycling speed
int CalScT;
float CalScS;
char ScSValue[32];

int DataCount=1; //File line comparison

struct store06 //TICtotD
{
    char defTotDc[16];
}stock06[512];


struct store08 //TICtotT
{
 char defTotTc[16];
}stock08[512];

    fTotDc=fopen("TICtotD.txt","r"); //Opens total distance 
    fscanf(fTotDc,"%16[^\n]%*.2f", stock06[DataCount].defTotDc);
    fTotTc=fopen("TICtotT.txt","r"); //Opens total time
    fscanf(fTotTc,"%16[^\n]%*.2f", stock08[DataCount].defTotTc);

    printf("|Distance        |Time            |Speed           |");
    printf("\n");

    printf("|%-16s",   stock06[DataCount].defTotDc); 
    printf("|%-16s",   stock08[DataCount].defTotTc);

    CalScD = atoi(stock06[DataCount].defTotDc); //Totals are converted to int for calculation
    CalScT = atoi(stock08[DataCount].defTotTc);

    if(CalScT == 0) //Test for 1/0 error, There is also a failsafe in the edit function which checks for t=0;
    {
                  if(CalScD == 0) //If distance is 0 (As it is by default), the speed is 0.
                  {       
                        printf("|0               ");
                  }
                  else  //If distance is not 0 , we have (1/0)*k, which doesn't exist.
                  {   
                        printf("|Error, Time is 0");//Error message given.
                  }
        }
        else
        {
             CalScS = CalScD/CalScT; 
             snprintf(ScSValue,32,"%.2f", CalScS); //Turns this int value into a string
             printf("|%-16s",ScSValue); //String outputted
        }

        printf("|"); //last column
        getch();
    }
```

This is the code for one line, given that this on a do-while loop until the end of the file.

Input (distance file): Line 1: 4 , (time file) Line 1: 1 .
Expected speed output: 0.25
Actual output: 0.00

Edit: My coding skills are RIP
Edit 2: The mistake, assuming interger/interger would automatically calculate a floating point value. I have changed the code accordingly, it works. Thank you guys.

Comment: atoi returns an integer. devising int/int gives an integer.You can multiply the first by 1.0 which will cast it to a float an the return value will be a float

Comment: I can recommend to use `double` instead of `float`.

Comment: @ShaZiv "multiply the first by 1.0 which will cast it to a float" is better stated as "multiply the first by 1.0 which will cast it to a double".  To get a `float` use `1.0f`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `CalScS = CalScD/CalScT;` first the **integer** division is executed, then the resulting value is converted to float and assigned to the variable.

Try this

```
CalScS = CalScD/(double)CalScT;
```

To first convert the denominator to floating point, then do the division and assign correctly.

Oh ... and (almost) always prefer `double` to `float`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
int CalScD;  //Values for total cycling speed
int CalScT;
```

both are of type `int`, and `CalScS` is of type `float`.

While calculating the division using

```
CalScS = CalScD/CalScT;
```

first, the division will be performed as integer division [resulting in an `int` value] and after that, the `int` result will be *promoted* to float. That's why you're getting the `integer` output.

change

```
CalScS = CalScD/CalScT;
```

to

```
CalScS = ((float)CalScD )/CalScT;
```

to enforce the floating point division.

Comment: @CoolGuy aah..sorry. i copied the code from the answer above. fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation line `CalScS = CalScD/CalScT;` is doing integer division, since both operands are integers.

You need one (or both) of the operands to be `float`s (or `double`s) to get floating-point division.